# ^C: this does not give me my commands back, what do I do?

Tags: reactjs

I put `^C` but that does not give me my previous commands back in the terminal for mac!

```
Last login: Sun Mar 24 21:17:01 on ttys000
azfars-MacBook-Pro:~ ausieebilal$ npm run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ausieebilal/.npm/_logs/2019-03-24T16_32_23_995Z-debug.log
azfars-MacBook-Pro:~ ausieebilal$
```

Comment: Sounds like a terminal shortcut problem. What made you tag it as reactjs problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? How is `^C` relevant? If you want to run an npm script (such as "build") you need to be in a project folder that contains a package.json file with that script - it seems like you're running the command from your home directory.

Comment: Please, put you `package.json` in your question